# Why is request body undefined in one route?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm having some troubles trying to stablish a REST API with nodeJS and express. The following code defines two routes, "stores" and "user".

Surprisingly, the route to "/user" is working nice but when a request arrives to "/stores" the request body appears undefined. I've searched for a solution but nothing seems to work for me.

Both controllers have the same structure.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
methodOverride = require("method-override"),
mongoose = require('mongoose');


// Connection to DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/appDB', function(err, res) {
if(err) throw err;
console.log('Connected to Database');
});


// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

//Import models and controllers
var userModel=require("./models/user.js")(app,mongoose);
var storeModel=require("./models/store.js")(app,mongoose);
var usersController=require("./controllers/users.js");
var storesController=require("./controllers/stores.js");

//Router options
var router=express.Router();



router.route('/stores')
.get(storesController.getNearestStores);

router.route('/user')
.post(usersController.addUser);

app.use(router);


//Start server
app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Node server running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

Thank you very much.

P.S.:First time with nodejs and express(and even mongo)

Comment: Could you post your stores controller?

Comment: What does the 'storesController.getNearestStores' function look like?

Comment: It was only that I was trying to retrieve parameters from a GET request. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no `body` on a `GET` request in the http standard. Only `POST` and `PUT`.

What you want to do instead is use a `query string`

```
get
/stores?location=mystore
```

this way on your callback you have access to req.query

```
req.query
{
    location: 'mystore'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body?rq=1)

This gave me the solution, get requests don't accept parameters under HTTP standard.